# Sh command never ends inside NodeJS + Typescript (while it does inside shell)

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker, sh

When I start a docker service, and I wait for it to start listening on a specific address via this shell command:

```sh
# Shell Script

(docker logs -f container_name &) | grep -m 1 "Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000"
echo "It will reach this point without problems"
```

everything works fine. The shell script pauses for some time on that line, and eventually it lets the script continue once the docker container logs contain the line `Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000`.

For some reason, though, it gets stuck when I do the same inside a Typescript script (executed with `ts-node` on NodeJS) (and I verified from the shell that the container logs reached the 'ready' line):

```js
import { execSync } from 'child_process'

console.log('Before exec, waiting for service to be ready')
execSync('(docker logs -f container_name &) | grep -m 1 "Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000"')
console.log('After exec, service ready')  // I never reach this point
```

I tried this same code with a simpler example, instead of using `docker logs`, just doing `cat` over a file... and it works fine as in the shell.

```js
import { execSync } from 'child_process'

console.log('Before exec, waiting for service to be ready')
execSync('(cat filename &) | grep -m 1 "line to wait for"')
console.log('After exec, we found the coincidence')  // We reach this point as expected
```

And that's the part I don't fully get, what's special about the interaction between docker & the Typescript script. It works as expected on POSIX Shell, it works as expected with Typescript when the command is just slightly simpler (with `cat`)... but it gets stuck for the specific case I propose here (it does not crash either, I tried using a wrong container name and in that case it crashes, it does not get stuck).

Any idea? Thank you for your time.

P.S.: I tried to encapsulate the command into a small shell script (and then call the shell script from NodeJS)... and it gets stuck as well. So... is it possible that NodeJS has some bug causing problems for commands that take too much time to execute?

Answer (score 0):

According to [execSync](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execsync_command_options) docs it won't return until the spawned process has fully closed. It seems `docker logs -f...` is not finishing and nodeJs is waiting for that.

This different approach should work (supposing your network is reachable from the host):

```
import { execSync } from 'child_process'

console.log('Before exec, waiting for service to be ready')
execSync('while (! curl localhost:8000 -I -s -q >/dev/null); do sleep 1; done')
console.log('After exec, service ready')
```